# Why is window moved event called?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl-2

The window moved event is triggered without moving my window causing my program to freeze.

In my SDL program, it has a random chance of freezing up after loading. Using a debugger I found what was causing it:
 1. my main loop reads SDL events until there are no more:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
```

2. according to the debugger, I keep getting a window event with the same values:

- type : 512 (windowEvent)

  windowID : 2

  event : 4 (I looked it up and this is the window moved event)

  padding1, padding2, padding3 : 0

  data1 : 756

  data 2 : 743

what could be causing these events to pop up? The window isn't being moved at all when these pop up.

Comment: I haven't done raw Windows messages in years, but it's possible this is one of those messages you always get on start-up to give you information e.g. the size or position or maximisation status of your new window. Is it really a problem - can you just ignore them or even process them anyway? FWIW the Windows constant `WM_MOVE` is 3 not 4, so I assume that's an SDL constant?

Comment: Yes, it is an SDL constant. (SDL_WINDOWEVENT)

Comment: When an event is gathered with SDL_Event, it is supposed to be removed from the event queue. The problem is that it keeps coming back up over and over, so my program gets locked up reading all the events.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I suggest you get the SDL source and debug into it to work out whether it's generating them itself or they're being generated by the windowing system (sorry, I missed the Ubuntu tag).

Comment: It's okay. I will investigate some more.